# How to link source files into Eclipse based IDE

Tags: eclipse, version-control, xilinx-edk

I am now at the beginning of software project for Xilinx Zynq SoC hardware platform. Xilinx company offers for software development their own Eclipse based IDE called Vitis. Due to version control reasons I need to have application source codes and custom IP peripheral drivers source codes in separate directories  (let´s say App_src and Drivers_src) and I need to link the Vitis project with the aforementioned source codes in such a manner that the source codes modification occurs in the directory which is under version control. It means that I need to prevent any copying of source codes into the workspace. Can anybody tell me how to resolve that in system manner i.e. with respect to the version control system usage? Thanks in advance for any ideas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the solution. There is the "Link folder" option in the project Properties. This enables to link given folder without copying it into the workspace. [image]

Answer (score 0):

When you import an existing project (`File > Import... > Existing Project into Workspace`) do not check the `Copy projects into workspace` checkbox to import the project into Eclipse IDE's workspace without moving its sources.

[image: import wizard]